# Property ' ' does not exist on type 'string | JwtPayload'

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I'm using jsonwebtoken to authenticate, I getting an issue : when i decode my token, i getting an error : Property'id | deviceId| exp' not exist on type 'string|JwtPayload'. Please help me how I solve it ? Thanks all very much !
Here is my  generateToken function and decode function

```
const payload = {
            id : userId, 
            deviceId
        }
public generateToken(payload : object, secretKey : string){
    return jwt.sign({...payload, exp : Math.floor(Date.now()/ 1000 + EXP_2_MIN)}, secretKey)
  }
   public static decode(token : string ) {
      return jwt.decode(token);
   }
```

Here is i'm trying to decode token :

```
async getSecretKey (request : Request)  {
        const headers = request.headers
        const payload   =  JwtStrategy.decode(headers['authorization'].split(" ")[1])
        const {id , deviceId, exp}  = payload
```

I'm expecting the token to decode into an object like my payload object